# XCode using scanf() in bug testing for iPhone app with no UI yet

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, console, scanf

I've created an Object that handles much logic on the back end. To be able to interact with this object, I will eventually create a UIViewController and nice UI that will send it method calls as it sees fit. Until then, however, I would like to bug test the logic in a real-like environment.

Is it possible to use scanf() in XCode's console to get keyboard input?

I have tried calling scanf() but it seems that the app just skips over the call and keeps the desired variable input as it's declared value creating an endless loop.

My code:

```
int active = 1;

do 
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Enter X Coordinate: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter Y Coordinate: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("\n");

    //Obj-C object method calls 

    //if meets condition: active--;
} 
while (active);
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible what i'm trying to do?

I'm running the code through XCode's simulator as opposed to Terminal (if this is the problem, OK but if you think its just *better* to run through Terminal instead of simulator than keep your opinion to yourself plz).

Comment: Did you try printing the values of x and y right after scanf, maybe it reads something.

Comment: yes, it prints '0' for both. 0 is the default value at declaration.

Comment: @EliGregory: Actually, 0 isn't the default value. Your variables are uninitialized. You're just lucky that they're coming up 0. You really should be paying attention to the return value of `scanf()` to find out if it actually read anything.

Comment: What version of xCode are you using? Please check.

Comment: @KevinBallard well I guess i'm lucky then but the code in //Obj-C object method calls tells me x and y are both valued at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `scanf()` with iOS apps.

Alternatively you could get you input by

1. Reading from a file.
2. Using the debugger
3. Making a quick GUI
4. Test your back end in a command line application

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian ... do you know why I can't use it? Also, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I've accepted your answer @Sebastian but I would still like to know why..?